# OnTabChanged doesn't fire

Tags: android

Trying to implement 2 Tabs in an Android app.  I can get all of the content to render by setting either setCurretTab() to 0 or 1 in OnCreate(), however, I cannot get onTabChanged() to fire,i.e. nothing happens when I click the tabs. Here's the code:

```
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      ...

      final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup(); 
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab0").setIndicator("tab0").setContent(R.id.content0)); 
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1").setContent(R.id.content1));
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
      tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        public void onTabChanged(String id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "anybody home?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("tab","this event never fires");                       
        }
    });

}
```

PS: I'm targeting api 10 using GoogleAPIs.

Answer (score -1):

Just implement the OnTabChanged interface

```
Class X implements OnTabChanged {
```

and use tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this) instead of tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){